# Simple Objective-C (applies to C) console program to convert fahrenheit to celsius and vice versa

Tags: c, objective-c

I am writing a simple console application in Objective-C but I have heard that this coding may be loosely applied to some C as well, so I wanted to make that clear.

I am having a slight problem however, when I run from the Debugger in Xcode, for some reason, my program does not wait for user input, it just rolls right on through, displaying the strings and converting a number automatically.

Is there a case for this?

Did I not specify something correct in my if else statement?

Here is my code:

```
//Simple program to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and Celsius to Fahrenheit

#import <stdio.h>

@interface Converter: NSObject
{
//Instance variable which stores converting formula for objects
double formula;
}

//Declare instance method for setting instance variable
-(double) convert: (double) expression;

//Declare instance method for getting instance variable
-(double) formula;

@end


@implementation Converter;

//Define instance method to set the argument (expression) equal to the instance variable
-(double) convert: (double) expression
{
formula = expression;
}

//Define instance method for returning instance variable, formula
-(double) formula
{
return formula;
}

@end

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

//Point two new objects, one for the Fahrenheit conversions and the other for the Celsius conversions, to the Converter class
Converter *fahrenheitConversion = [[Converter alloc] init];
Converter *celsiusConversion = [[Converter alloc] init];

//Declare two double variables holding the user-inputted data, and one integer variable for the if else statement   
double fahrenheit, celsius;
int prompt;

NSLog(@"Please press 0 to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, or 1 to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius\n ");
scanf("%i", &prompt);
if(prompt == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Please enter a temperature in Celsius to be converted into Fahrenheit!:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &celsius);
    [fahrenheitConversion convert: ((celsius*(9/5)) + 32)];
    NSLog(@"%lf degrees Celsius is %lf Fahrenheit", celsius, [fahrenheitConversion formula]);
}

else {
    NSLog(@"Please enter a temperature in Fahrenheit to be converted into Celsius!:\n");
    [celsiusConversion convert: ((fahrenheit - 32)*(5/9))];
    NSLog(@"%lf degrees Fahrenheit is %lf Celsius", fahrenheit, [celsiusConversion formula]);
}

return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks as though the reason the console in the Xcode debugger did not wait for my input was because I had it set as an iPhone application, not a Mac OS X Cocoa, I can't even remember why I did that.  What I really should do is just make a project with no template, so it doesn't expect anything..

I'm still really appreciative and open to suggestions like dreamlax, and I'm trying to implement your code suggestion, it's a little harder than expected though, because I'm still very new.

Comment: That's a very polite and enthusiastic application you have there :)

Comment: Ahaha, :) yup, I'm actually quite proud of it xD

Everything works fine, except when I run it, it just skips through every line of code, except the calculations are great..  I just included some newly updated code, as if it wasn't already clear enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `scanf`, always check the return value. It will return however many items were successfully scanned. In your application, you only provide one argument, so if `scanf` was successful, then it should return 1. It can return two other values:

1. If there was an error reading input, or if the input ended before successfully scanning all format descriptions, `scanf` may return `EOF`.
2. If there was no input that matched the format description provided, `scanf` may return 0 (this may happen if the user provided an alphabetic character instead of a number, or if the user just pressed enter without typing anything, etc.)

You should check the result of each `scanf` call and handle it appropriately.

```
int result = scanf("%i", &prompt);

if (result == EOF || result == 0)
{
    NSLog (@"There was an error reading your choice.");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    // result should be 1 here, continue onwards doing work
}
```

There could be a number of reasons why `scanf` may not return 1 while running through a debugger, here's a few that I can think of:

1. `stdin` is closed for some reason, so reading from `stdin` will always fail.
2. There could be some data being piped into your application's `stdin` stream. I'm not sure where this could come from.

#### Some further advice

It may be better if you store the temperature in your class using only a single scale. For example:

```
@interface Temperature : NSObject
{
    double celsius; // only store one temperature
}

- (id) initWithFahrenheit:(double) f;
- (id) initWithCelsius:(double) c;

- (double) fahrenheitValue;
- (double) celsiusValue;
@end

@implementation Temperature
 - (id) initWithFahrenheit:(double) f
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    celsius = (f - 32)*(5/9);
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCelsius:(double) c
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    celsius = c;
    return self;
}

- (double) fahrenheitValue
{
    return (celsius*(9/5)) + 32);
}

 - (double) celsiusValue
{
    return celsius;
}

@end
```

Then, if you have a value in fahrenheight, you can do:

```
 Temperature *myTemp = [[Temperature alloc] initWithFahrenheit:f];
 double celsius = [myTemp celsiusValue];
```

See if you can implement other temperature scales too, such as Kelvin, and Rankine!

Comment: Good idea about other scales, never heard of Rankine though..  OK, cool, what about your line where result == 0 is included in the same line as EOF.  Why is that?  Also, why did you set it equal to result, and not prompt?  Is that just a standard naming technique?

Comment: Also, in your suggested code, is it basically just taking one Celsius value and having the extendibility to be converted into anything else from celsius?  That makes more sense when I add Kelvin and Rankine.  I guess it would be really cool to select you "base" temperature, and then be able to convert that temperature into any of the others.

Comment: @BOSS: `scanf` *returns* the number of items successfully scanned, I called the variable `result` but if it were more verbosely named it could be called `scannedItems` or `numberOfSuccessfullyScannedItems` to be uber-verbose. I check for both `EOF` and `0` in one go because both of these would indicate that it did not successfully scan a number into the `prompt` variable. You are correct about having just one Celsius value and have each of the other temperature scales convert from the Celsius value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"%d"` in format for scanf instead of `"%i"`:

```
scanf("%d", &prompt);
```

Comment: Actually, with the way I had this setup, isn't it correct to use %i in my case, because I instantiated the prompt variable as an integer, as it won't deal with floating points or double precision data types, just because the user was instructed to type in either 0 or 1 into the console.  This also didn't appear to affect my problem upon running either..  Thanks though.